# Use of "ja" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, german-to-english, standard-german

In the following sentence:

> Na gut, dann kann ich ja ab sofort auf Deutsch schreiben.

Why is *ja* used? What's its function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [modal particle](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adverb/Partikel/Modalpartikel.html). (→[English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_modal_particle))

Unlike "normal" adverbs (`gut können`), modal particles don't directly describe the verb (`ja können`?), but the speaker's relation to the action. Among other things, they can describe expectations/assumptions, as `ja` does here.

In this context, it modifies the verb *können* somewhat like this:

> Alright, then it is possible for me to write in German from now on.
> →
> Alright, then it's ok for me to write in German from now on.

---

**Edit:** Although *können* is obviously not used in the sense of "being able to" here, there are contexts where it's not as unambiguous. So here's another comparison:

> ...aber du musst jetzt gehen. *...but you have to go now. (really)*
> →
> ...aber du musst ja jetzt gehen. *...but you can't stay any longer. / ...but have to go now, don't you?
>
> (not because of the situation "here", but because of some reason inherent to you)*

Or

> Das ist schlecht. *That is bad. (factually)*
> →
> Das ist ja schlecht. *Well, that's bad. / That's bad, isn't it? / That's just bad.*

Comment: I think the ambiguity of "können" clutters the frame a bit. I'd suggest showing the difference using a sentence with "müssen", for example... "Dann muss ich jetzt Deutsch schreiben" vs. "Dann muss ich ja jetzt Deutsch schreiben"... that way we could really see what "ja" does, and not how "ja" interacts with the highly context dependent "können"

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. But what is the takeaway for "ja" from this answer ... that it changes "possible" to "ok"? Both these examples can be read as an assumption or a statement of fact, so they're just showing different interpretations of "können" and do not really tell much about what "ja" does

Comment: Actually no :)... the examples are good, but you translated "ja" the way "doch" would be translated. "ja" does not seek affirmation that openly. It affirms and there might be different reasons why such affirmation would be put into a sentence. In the first example it might well be intended as a sort of reproach like... "We could have had a good time, but du musst ja jetzt gehen, so it's YOUR fault that we won't" In another context it might be used to reaffirm the the listener that he or she has to go. IN either case, it does not ask for affirmation.

Comment: Same for the second. Without any context my translation would be "Wow, that is bad". So in this case it adds some element of surprise, to some degree about how bad it actually is. What it doesn't do is asking to be agreed with. You should remove the "isn't it" from the second and change the "don't you" from the first translation, imo. As it stands it does not reflect what "ja" does, especially when you compare it with "doch" in the very same examples.

Comment: @Emanuel In your example the whole sentence is used sarcastically. To me, *ja* can point out an external reason/cause, thus *affirming* it implicitly. "Wow, that is bad." is represented with "Well, that's *bad*.". Question tags do not necessarily ask for confirmation: You're *some* gal, ain't you?

Comment: @Emanuel Added a bit to the first example.

Answer (score 6):

I often use the modal 'ja' as a way to suggest to the other that there is an agreement between us on the topic I'm talking about, or on a premise to a conclusion I'm drawing.
The emotional quality of the 'ja' is defined by exactly what that topic/conclusion is. It always introduces a degree of emotion or at least subjectivity into a sentence otherwise formulating a neutral statement. It is therefore often used to suggest to the other that this subjective perspective is a common one, making it a cheap, unsuspicious and popular rhetorical means if you want to persuade someone. This is also the reason why it is often considered bad style in a speech.

In addition to the other examples, two more from me:

> Das ist ja ein riesiger Baum!
>   Das ist ein riesiger Baum!

In the first case, your point would be that you feel overwhelmed by the dimensions of that particular vegetational specimen. In the second, you are actually stating that by some reference, the precise meterage of this one categorises it as "huge", unlike the one next to it that only qualifies as "mighty big".

There is a big variety of things this 'ja' can express. It may also be a sudden idea:

> Wenn kein Fisch anbeißt, können wir Pilze sammeln.
>   Wenn kein Fisch anbeißt, können wir ja Pilze sammeln.

The first just names an option in the current situation. However, you might also go and collect firewood. The second phrase tells your partner(s) that picking mushrooms is an enjoyable thing to do by itself, and depending on their personal likings might not only make up for the luckless fishing, but even be more enjoyable than fishing in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

"ja"  is normally a positive reaction to a question as "yes". But in German "ja" has a lot of other uses, not possible with English yes.
Examples: Das ist ja nicht wahr!- Das ist ja gelogen! - Das ist ja falsch! 
Formerly such words were called Füllwörter, filling words, but that's rather a stopgap, it doesn't help a learner in any way.

Today one uses terms such as modality particle. But to say it clearer, with 'ja" a speaker can give a lot of additional information as to his attitude to the statement.
It can express indignation as in: Das ist ja gelogen!
It can express empathy as in: Das ist ja schlimm.
Admiration: Das ist ja ein tolles Kleid!
If you study these uses of "ja" in adverb position before adjectives or verb forms
you will find that it can express quite a lot of emotions of the speaker or his attitude towards his statement.

duden.de has tried to analyse the uses of "ja" used as modality particle more closely and gives examples farther below.
http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ja

In a lot of cases one could explain this special use of "ja" as the remainder of a second sentence such as "Ja, so ist es wirklich". Only the first word of this second sentence remains and is built into the first sentence. Or: Ja, das ist klar, das weiß jeder.